# Open Firebug Lite

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebug, firebug-lite

I don't know why, but every time I try to use firebug lite it's a pain to get it to appear.

I am using this link:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>
```

How are you supposed to get it to appear if you don't use the option startOpened - true? I don't see any icons or anything onscreen. So I usually use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js#startOpened=true"></script>
```

But today, not even that is working...

And it is loading, I can see the firebug-lite.js in the Resources of regular inspect element.

Comment: @GW Does it work on an iPad?

Comment: I use a firebug lite bookmarklet, try this out http://osxdaily.com/2011/12/02/run-firebug-on-ipad-or-iphone/ if ok I post this comment as answer

Comment: i didn't know about that "startOpened=true" option. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have the real Firebug installed, then the option `disableWhenFirebugActive` (default `true`) will disable FirebugLite (see https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Options):

You can try:

```
https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js#startOpened=true,disableWhenFirebugActive=false
```