# Open firebug lite through javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, firebug-lite

I want to open firebug lite through javascript code. I didnt find any proper solution. Can anyone help on this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js#startOpened=true"></script>
```

More about it [here](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Options)

Comment: Actullay i tried with the below code. But its working for some urls. not all. browser.setUrl("javascript:(function(F,i,r,e,b,u,g,L,I,T,E){if(F.getElementById(b))return;E=F[i+'NS']&&F.documentElement.namespaceURI;E=E?F[i+'NS'](E,'script'):F[i]('script');E[r]('id',b);E[r]('src',I+g+T);E[r](b,u);(F[e]('head')[0]||F[e]('body')[0]).appendChild(E);E=new%20Image;E[r]('src',I+L);})(document,'createElement','setAttribute','getElementsByTagName','FirebugLite','4','firebug-lite.js','releases/lite/latest/skin/xp/sprite.png','https://getfirebug.com/','#startOpened');") ;

Comment: Try the solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816670/open-firebug-lite

Comment: I am not creating my own jsp page. i render the code with browser. I mean browser.setUrl(); Any other solutions?

Comment: Thanks a lot Achilles. I will try.